# spring boot deployment to kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I'm going to deploy my test spring boot application to kubernetes. But I am not java developer.

My deployment scenario is:

1. ./gradlew build
2. Docker image build with .jar into build/libs/*.jar
3. write the deployment.yaml and service too.
4. check.

But I have a problem I did build process. Because the datasource.url was the localhost. I want to use `datasource.url:postgresql-service:5432/test_db`. But My `Dockerfile` already package my app as localhost. In kubernetes, It is already broken because my app cannot find my database pod.

Q) if the app cannot connect my database, I cannot build my app locally. How do I solve this problem?

p.s) spring boot 3.1 / application.yml / Kotlin / Gradle

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar

COPY ./build/libs/sunnyside-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./usr/src/app/build/libs/sunnyside-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "/usr/src/app/build/libs/sunnyside-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: The Dockerfile you show doesn't suggest any connection to a database or any particular `spring.datasource.url` value.  What prevents you from building the image?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a container to Kubernetes (or any other platform) the configuration should be provided at runtime via external configuration (environment variables, Kubernetes ConfigMaps or Secrets).

For Spring Boot you can set the configuration via file or environment variables.

The simplest way is to add the environment variable to your deployment: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` - this will override the configuration in the container:

```yaml
...
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: "postgresql-service:5432/test_db"
...
```

---

Another thing: I would recommend to build your container image using the Spring Boot feature for that (`./gradlew bootBuildImage`). See [docs for Spring Boot Gradle Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image).

Comment: Nice sharing for me. Thank you.

Comment: you can vote the answer up if you like it and you can mark it as correct / solved